# htaccess: limit file access but allow for specific folder

Tags: .htaccess

My current htaccess prevents hot linking and direct download of files but its also blocking download from within the site. if the user is at `http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com/portal/WHATEVER` then allow download, that's what i'm trying to achieve any advice?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(pdf|xls|xlsx|docx|doc)$ https://www.sub.domain.com/login.php [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: You should never offer  documents directly for download by placing them inside the document root. You should _always_ have a handler which controls access to the documents and only hands out their content when authorized.

Comment: You realize this is completely fruitless and that HTTP headers can be spoofed, right?

Comment: @arkascha unfortunately i'm not the original program, I would have set it up differently and the right way. putting the docs in a folder behind a protected area.... Right now i'm just patching what's already been done

Comment: @Qix i'm aware, it's not my system/code ... i wrote the htaccess code to help patch a problem that was not setup correctly in the first place.

Comment: Are they two different domains? a sub domain and the reguarl domain? Which domain needs access to which?

Comment: @PanamaJack sub.domain.com/portal/ needs access